# Need help understanding proof that there always exists a closed orbit.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I know every orbit $G.x$ is open in $\overline{G.x}$, and if we assume that $G.x$ is not closed then $\overline{G.x}\setminus G.x$ is a union of orbits.

It is then claimed that the dimension of $\overline{G.x}\setminus G.x$ is strictly less that the dimension of $G.x$. I want to know know how is this true, and also how does it follow from this that the orbit with minimal dimension has to be closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By hypothesis $Z_1 := \overline {Gx} \backslash Gx$ is a proper closed subset in $\overline {Gx}$, so $\dim Z_1 < \dim \overline{Gx}$.

For the induction step : let $x_1 \in Z_1$, if $Gx_1$ is closed the claim is proved, else you can take again $Z_2 = \overline{Gx_1} \backslash Gx_1$, pick a point $x_2 \in Z_2$ and so one. If this procedure doesn't stop for any $Z_i$ of positive dimension, you will end with a $G$-invariant set of dimension zero which certainly contains a closed orbit.

Comment: Orbits form a stratification of $X$, and strata of minimal dimension are closed.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a little confused about comparing the dimensions of the orbits. Why is $\dim(G.x_1) < \dim(G.x)$?

Comment: Because $G.x_1 \subset Z_1$ (since $Z_1$ is $G$-invariant) so $\dim G.x_1 \leq \dim Z_1 < \dim Gx$.

Comment: @100110 I just edited my answer, because if the procedure doesn't stop, $Z_n$ is not necessary a fixed point, but hopefully it's a finite $G$-invariant subset, so it contains a closed orbit (just take any orbit in $Z_n$). Don't hesitate to ask if you still have any questions.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure if I get why $Z_i$ are $G$-invarient. I think I understand everything else that's happening. If the process doesn't stop, we end up with a finite $G$-invariant subset $Z_n$ which is finite, therefore closed in $X$, and then any orbit in this set is also closed being finite.

Comment: @100110 : Exactly. Now, $Z_i$ are $G$-invariant because if $A$ is $G$-invariant and $B \subset A$ is $G$-invariant, then $ A \backslash B$ is also $G$-invariant. Indeed, if $x \in A \backslash B$ but $gx \in B$ for some $g$, in particular $gx \in B$ but $g^{-1} \cdot (gx) \notin B$ which contradicts that $B$ is $G$-invariant.

Comment: Since $Gx$ is $G$-invariant, so is $\overline{Gx}$.  This follows from the property that if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a continuous function, then $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$ for all $E \subseteq A$.  Since $\overline{Gx}$ and $Gx$ are $G$-invariant, so is $\overline{Gx} - Gx$.  A $G$-invariant set is the same thing as a union of orbits.

Comment: @D_S : thanks a lot for adding all the missing elements !

Answer (score 5):

**Proposition**:Let $X$ be a variety, $U$ a dense open subset, and $Z$ the complement of $U$ in $X$.  Then $Z$ has strictly lower dimension than $X$.

Proof: Let $X_1, ... , X_t$ be the irreducible components of $X$, and let $Z_1, ... , Z_s$ be the irreducible components of $Z$.  So the dimension of $X$ (resp. $Z$) is the maximum of the dimension of the $X_i$ (resp. $Z_i$).

Since $U$ is dense in $X$, $U$ has nonempty intersection with each $X_i$.  For if, say, $U \cap X_1 = \emptyset$, then $U$ and hence $\overline{U} = X$ is contained in the closed set $X_2 \cup \cdots \cup X_t$, which is properly contained in $X$.

Since $Z_i$ is irreducible, it is contained in one of the maximal irreducible subsets of $X$, say $X_j$.  And the containment must be proper, because $U \cap X_j$ is nonempty.  Now a proper, closed, irreducible subset of an irreducible variety must be of strictly lower dimension.  So each of the $Z_1, ... , Z_s$ has strictly less dimension than that of some irreducible component of $X$.  $\blacksquare$

Now take $X = \overline{Gx}, U = Gx$.

N.H.'s answer explains the rest: there exist orbits of minimal dimension, and any such orbit $Gx$ must be closed.  Otherwise, $\overline{Gx} - Gx$ is a union of orbits of strictly lower dimension.

Comment: Your answer's also very helpful. Thank you so much.